# How to return only the Date with formate from a SQL Server DateTime datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I know there are many questions related to this. I try to find my answer but can't able to find it.

when I write `SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate()) from tblBlogs`

this query its give me result like this `2018-09-10`

but I want to `10, September, 2018`

I hope someone helps me

Comment: What is your sql-server version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your SQL-server version higher than 2012 you can try to use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to make it.

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(),'dd,MMMM,yyy')
```

[sqlifddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7703e7b19f97c5b98d40ecea8af6be63)

---

Or you can use `DATENAME` function get the name to be your expect result.

```
SELECT DATENAME(day,Getdate())+','+DATENAME(month,Getdate())+','+DATENAME(year,Getdate())
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3bc00a4d8f23bf55c8953a2520e2d7de)

**Result**

```
10,September,2018
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I try to avoid `FORMAT` as it can be awfully slow when applied against a dataset. Another method would be to use `DATENAME`:

```
DATENAME(DAY,GETDATE()) +', ' + DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE()) + ', ' + DATENAME(YEAR,GETDATE())
```

However, if it is for the display format often it's best to do that in your presentation layer, rather than the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL Server does not support `FORMAT` function

```
SELECT CAST(DAY(@DateTime) AS VARCHAR) + ', ' + DATENAME(MONTH, @DateTime) + ', ' + CAST(YEAR(@DateTime) AS VARCHAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

try using `FORMAT`

you can specify your date format whatever you want

```
SELECT FORMAT(getdate(),'dd,MMMM,yyy') from tblBlogs;
```